# Why getting error when updating MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building backend with MEAN stack, but when I try to update document in the db i am getting an error:

```
 topUp = function(name, amount, callback) {
    User.updateOne(
        { "name" : name },
        { $set: { "wallet": amount } },
        function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            callback();
        });
 };
```

**TypeError: User.updateOne is not a function**

But e.g. findOne() works fine:

```
    User.findOne({
                name: decoded.name
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;

                i

f (!user) {
                return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
            } else {
                //res.json({success: true, info: {wallet: user.wallet, userPic: user.userPic}});
                topUp(decoded.name, amount, function() {
                    User.close();
                });
            }
        });
```

"User" is a Mongo model file.

Comment: because `findOne` is a predefined function but `updateOne()` is not. It should by default update only one record. You can use `multi: true` to update multiple records.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj well, according to Mongo docs updateOne() is predefined too: [proof](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/update/)

Comment: I think it's not defined in the database driver that you might be using. I think you are using Mongoose and `updateOne()` is not available there. You cannot use all native mongodb functions with all drivers.

Comment: I am not very sure about it, but that is so as per my understanding.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj wow, thanks a lot, that's true! I should have used update() which is supported by Mongoose instead of updateOne(). If you write it as an answer I will be glad to accept it:)

Comment: Glad to know it helped :). I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not defined in the database driver that you might be using. I think you are using Mongoose and `updateOne()` is not available there. You cannot use all native mongodb functions with all drivers

Answer (score 0):

There is an en existing enhancement request for this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3997 , but maybe the [findByIdAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) method could be a close alternative.