# Confusing error message using updateOne() function on a mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

To summarize, I have a mongodb database with a 'groupcollection' in it. One of the attributes is called 'deleted' and it has values either true or false. I want to update the value of 'deleted' for a specific document using 'groupname' as the query attribute. However, when I try the code below I receive the error "TypeError: collection.updateOne is not a function"

```
    router.post('/deletegroup', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('groupcollection');

    var filter = {"groupname" : req.body.groupname};
    var updates = { $set: {"deleted" : true} };

    collection.updateOne(filter, updates, function(err) {
       if (err) {
           // If it failed, return error
           res.send("There was a problem deleting the group from the database.");
       }
       else {
       // And forward to success page
       res.redirect("grouplist");
       }
       });
    });
```

I've read the documentation on updateOne() for Node.js from mongoDB and I can't seem to figure out the reason for the error. Also, I am still very new to javascript/nodejs/mongo so I would greatly appreciate more informative answers!

Comment: Is it the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460397/why-getting-error-when-updating-mongodb

Comment: @arunes i'm using monk not mongoose but after researching more it does seem that monk doesn't define updateOne() :( any other ideas to get the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was using unique IDs for each group and instead of using updateOne() just using update() and having the unique ID as the query to make sure that I don't modify groups with the same name